# Deploying libgdx project from Intellij IDEA in one .jar file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, libgdx

After a lot of effort I managed to deploy LibGdx project from Intelij IDEA, but it has some issues. Running java –jar app.jar gave errors concerning path variables. So at first I made absolute paths (c:/etc.. ) which did a trick but obviously didn’t do much in a manner of deployment. 
Then I made relative paths “./assets/pic.png” and copied my assets folder in the same folder as .jar file which did a trick for the textures but not for the skin, which had to be in the same folder as .jar. Obviously, this made code runnig from Intelij to have path errors.

Is there a way to put and linked resources in .jar so that I’m not forced to manually copy resources and change paths in code?

Comment: Use `gradlew dist` to generate a compiled jar that has the assets folder included inside it.

Comment: Tanks for this simple solution but linking project with gradle and runing gradlew.bat resolted in .jar having 'no main manifest attribute' error. 
It works fine for deployment under Eclipse dough.